# How to Create a Expandable List View in a linear Layout at another linear layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I try so many times but why I cann't do it I don't know. After I declare Expandable List view this:

```
listView =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
```

And I create My adapter as like ;

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
                { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
                { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
                { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
        };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(ExpandableList1.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

And then I set my adapter to listView.

```
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But There is so many problem I cannot create ;
İf u help me I will be so happy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks guyss I handle my problem, all problem is that don't extends ExpandableListActivity, just Activity it is my code. Now I try to learn how to focus group when a click a button.
Here is code.

```
public class expandXml extends Activity{

ExpandableListView listView;
ExpandableListAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deneme2);


    listView =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    listView.setFocusable(true);
     adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter() {


        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
                { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
                { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
                { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
        };
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView textView = getGenericView();
                textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
                return textView;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groups.length;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView textView = getGenericView();
                textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
                return textView;
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return childPosition;
        }

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(expandXml.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);

            return textView;
        }

    };
    listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Object x =adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            //Object o = this.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            String key =x.toString();
             Toast.makeText(expandXml.this,"Secildi "+key ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            return true;
        }
    });
    Button butex = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    butex.setOnClickListener(expandgroup);



    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private OnClickListener expandgroup = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listView.expandGroup(3);



    }
}; }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't find error unless you post the error log but try to refer to those links:

[ExpandableListView on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)

[Simple ExpandableListView Demo](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-expandable-listview.html)

[Custom ExpandableListView on Android](http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting this list adapter like you are:

```
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You should be setting it like this:

```
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```